# Adding a hyphen to [tag:remotesensing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It seems that "remote sensing" is two separate words, so the [remotesensing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remotesensing) tag should have a hyphen (i.e., be [remote-sensing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-sensing)). (I do not *think* this justifies having a synonym.)

---

I am tagging this [discussion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) even though I do not *think* there would be much debate about whether "remote sensing" should be treated as two words.

Comment: On the other hand, there is [tag:earth-observation] which is a subset of remote sensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there should be a hyphen. I edited the one question with the tag, although it is closed and will likely be deleted sometime, resulting in the tag being lost.

Comment: This is moderator only, but another procedure to rename tags is using the merge option when creating synonyms, and it'll be done _in the background_ without additional revisions to the questions that were using the previous tag name. It can also be helpful when the previous tag name already had a tag wiki, so we don't create orphaned tag wikis and need to manually copy/paste. Just thought it's worth mentioning, I realized this is an option just a few weeks ago myself too, when I wondered how Anna Lear did that for some tags that this was requested for and before we had our own pro tem mods. ;)

Comment: I noticed that it only had one question but not that the question was closed. Well, thanks anyway for what will become nothing. (Sigh.)